# Exchange Server name

Tags: exchange, activesync, name

I have a site running Exchange 2013, and while setting it up initially for ActiveSync or remote HTTPS access, I was able to somehow obtain an alphanumeric server name eg: 7d59d4a4-6b8f-4def-a960-8b4a3256e7a4@domain.com.

this needs Connect via HTTP enabled with the standard OWA URL entered, and the self-signed certificate installed on the user's laptop.

this name has helped a lot because it works beautifully in all cases, whether internally or externally.

Unfortunately I dont know how to duplicate the steps I took to get this name. I have another independent site with Exchange 2007 and would really like to know if there is a way to get a similar server name for this server.

Answer (score 2):

That name is for internal use only, and it's not supposed to be explicitly used anywhere, *especially* in URLs, which should be configured using the server's internal hostname and/or public-facing FQDN.

I don't know what you're using that name for, but you should stop doing that, and configure your Exchange server in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the objectGUID attribute from Active Directory.  I'm not sure how you ended up setting the name to that particular attribute but you can easily get that data from any AD objects attribute tab or with a simple Powershell query.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer 'name of your server' | Select ObjectGUID
```

Of course Get-ADUser, etc. works for other object types as well.  Keep in mind that the length of that name far exceeds the NetBIOS name limit of 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for precisely. That alphanumeric domain nmae looks like a mailbox to me. Anyways, did you try testexchangeconnectivity.com? You should be able to see autodiscovery output there which might include what you are looking for.